# Spittings, shellings, etc

Tags: dialect, yiddish

One quaint usage we have in Yiddish is the suffix  -echts which converts a verb to a noun. It is usually used with unsavory items like saliva (speiechts) or a pile of sunflower seed shells (schâllechts). Lubricating grease is schmierechts, and I’ve seen a ragged outfit descirbed as ântuechts. I’ll offer two questions for the group, the first one being: is there an equivalent formation in standard German?

My other question is only vaguely related, but it apparently uses the same suffix. There is a chemical compound associated with bootmaking written approximately as dziegechets. It’s undoubtedly Slavic but I wonder if anyone here recognizes it?

PS I hope nobody minds that I've linked to my own Yiddish musical translation of the epic ballad by I.L. Peretz, ["Monish"](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA8C41472147C38FC&feature=plcp/%22Monisch%22). You can watch the Yiddish subtitles and get some idea of exactly how much German is involved, and also you'll see how I've denoted the vowel shifts..

EDIT: I think I'm going to repost the Monish link as a lead-in to a separate question: would you agree that Yiddish is a dialect of German? I'm going to post that right now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is an equivalent usage of the suffix in non-dialect standard German, even though there seems to be a vowel change involved:

> kehren - Kehricht

This is however an unusual case. For common suffixes when bulding nouns from verbs see [this nice overwiew](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/V-To-N/Suffig.html?MenuId=WordFormation11131).

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. What dialect is that found in, and can you think of any more examples?

Comment: *"Kehricht"* is not dialect but its a dying old word. I couldn't find any more examples (but there should be).

Comment: Maybe "Dickicht" is another example? (Thicket = thickening, to be consistent with the pattern of making a noun from a verb.) But there's nothing especially unsavory about a thicket.

Comment: Or if not unsavory, maybe at least disorderly. Does that characterize the "icht" suffix?

Answer (score 1):

As for the suffix, you might consider the German "-ung", which replaces the standard verb ending "-en" to change it into a noun, such as changing *prüfen* to *Prüfung* and so on.

Comment: Yes, of course Yiddish has "ung" as well. The funny thing about the "echts" ending is that it always seems to make an unsavory substance out of an action.

Answer (score 1):

Takkat has offered "kehricht" (sweepings) as a possible example of a construction similar to the Yiddish "speiechts" (spittings). But I recently came across "Dickicht" (thicket, or "thickening" to maintain the parallel.) Is this an example of the same thing? Nothing unsavory about a thicket, but it is at least disorderly. Is there a pattern here?