# Pejorative gerund

Tags: grammar, terminology

Take a look at the following words:

> Gelaufe,
>   Gelerne,
>   Geschufte,
>   Geballer,
>   Geschredder,
>   Geschwätz,
>   Gelaber

There seems to be an construction one could call "pejorative gerund", which nominalizes a verb into something regarded pointless, boring, annoying and/or repititive. Although nouns like

> *Geverbarikadiere, *Geharpuniere, *Geprogrammiere

sound at least grammatical in my ears, they also appear to be *very* awkward. I suppose the construction is generally possible, but practically restricted to a certain subclass of verbs.

Do you how this construct is called in proper linguistical terms, and where I can find more about it? Of course, if you can tell me more about the rules of applicability, it would be interesting, too.

Comment: Gerund here is a wrong term. A gerund has the form of the infinitive used as a neuter noun: fahren - das Fahren, rauchen - das Rauchen. The term Verbalsubstantiv is also used.

Comment: @rogermue While being the wrong term technically, it does serve the same grammatical purpose as the "true" Gerund. More important is that this construction is **not** pejorative per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Takkat has answered the why.
I'd answer the second half of the question about the how by noting that your examples all have two or three syllables.

> Ge-lauf-e,
>   Ge-lern-e, 
>   Ge-schuft-e,
>   Ge-ball-er,
>   Ge-schredd-er,
>   Ge-schwätz,
>   Ge-lab-er

So it comes down to phonetics again. It just does not sound good and is to hard to say if you have more than three syllables.
Example Ge-lauf-e you have e- something - e or 1 2 1

> Ge-rum-ge-hüpfe

Duplication could be used to make it sound funny

> Geprogrammiere

Here what you do instead is to say

> Rumgeprogrammiere or Herumgeprogrammiere

So the rum or the herum balances the word.

> Rum - Ge - Programmier-e 2 1 2 1

where the 1 stands for an e and the 2 for something else.

> Schwadronieren --> geschwadroniere

does not work

> Schwadronieren --> herum-ge-schwadro-nie-re

works 2 1 2 1 1

Answer (score 13):

The pejorative meaning in your interesting examples may have a different reason as the prefix *"Ge-"* is by not means pejorative by itself.

It originates etymologically from the Old High German prefix *"ga-"*, or *"gi"* in the meaning of *togetherness* or *being in a collective*.

This can best be seen by the examples given in the *[Etymologisches Wörterbuch nach Pfeifer](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ge-&view=1)*:

> - *Gefährte, Genosse, Geselle, Gespiele, Gevatter*
> - *Gebilde, Gebirge, Geflügel, Gerippe, Gestirn, Getier, Gezweig*
> - *Gebäck, Gedeck, Gedicht, Geflecht, Gestell, Getöse*

Hence the prefix *"Ge-"* is also used to intensify a meaning by putting it into a collective context:

> - Gebrüll, Geflüster, Geschrei, Geschwätz, Gewühl

Similarly it can also be used with verbs and adjectives.

Sometimes a negative connotation may then result from this intensification which can further be increased by adding another prefix *"Herum-"* (used similarly):

> Herumgeirre, Herumgealbere, Herumgeschwätz, …

Comment: This recalls for me an [earlier discussion](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/spittings-shellings-etc) in which he offered the suffix "icht" as an instance of turning a verb into a noun with unsavory connotations. At that time he was only able to come up with *kehricht* (sweepings?) as an example. I wonder if anyone can think of others on this pattern? At the time, I had a number of Yiddish examples that seemed to use this form: spittings, shellings, smearings (speiechts, schallechts, schmierechts).

Answer (score 5):

Ending those verbs with -rei is another way to make nouns out of, and I think it *feels* correct for them:

> verbarrikadiererei,
>   harpuniererei,
>   programmiererei

Answer (score 0):

Wortbildungen wie Gebälk, Gebäck, Geschrei fallen unter den Begriff Kollektiva 
(Sammelbegriffe).
http://www.knoefler.cc/tag/kollektiva/