# What is the meaning of "Rumgejuxe"?

Tags: meaning

Does anyone know what the meaning of "Rumgejuxe" is?
I assume it is related to "juxen" or something, but I'm not sure.
I googled it, but it does not have many matches.

Comment: Closely related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/pejorative-gerund

Answer (score 25):

There are a few nouns of the form *Ge-* + *-e* derived from verbs:

> das Gebrüll(e), Gehabe, Gelaber(e), Geklopfe, Gelache, Gerede, Getue, Gezanke, ...

The meaning is pejorative, i.e. the activity denoted by the noun is perceived as being unpleasant.

So *Gejuxe* is a noun derived from *juxen* (*to joke*). The prefix *(he)rum* literally means *around*; here, it denotes an activity without a goal (as it can in English as well). Which leads us to *Rumgejuxe* ~ *the act of joking around*.

Comment: "Durch ihr Herumgebrülle hat Sonja wahrscheinlich die Hyänen vertrieben." "Sein Herumgejuxe hat einen Headhunter für die Comedybühne aufmerksam gemacht." Ich würde sagen die Bedeutung des Wortes ist neutral - erst der Kontext macht eine Unterscheidung in abwertenden Gebrauch oder nicht möglich.

Comment: Ich sehe die Grundbedeutung durchaus als abwertend. Daß negative Dinge auch positive Effekte haben können, steht außer Frage.

Comment: Abgesehen von Abstrakta wie "das Negative" oder "der Schaden" usw. glaube ich nicht, dass es objektiv negative Dinge überhaupt gibt. Wenn 2 Personen Zeuge eines Rumgejuxes werden, einer findet es schlecht, einer gut, wieso sollten unterschiedliche Begriffe dafür verwenden? Was spricht für den, der es gut findet, dagegen, das auch Rumgejuxe zu nennen?

Comment: Weil es beim Hörer eine andere Erwartung wecken würde. Deshalb würde derjenige, dem es gefällt, vielleicht von einem *Heidenspaß* sprechen. -- Um die Einstufung als "abwertend" plausibel zu machen, schaue man sich die Kollokationen von *Gerede* an: *leeres, sinnloses, dummes,* ... . Dagegen *Gespräch*: *klärendes, konstruktives, gutes, nettes, ...*

Comment: A) Ein Heidenspaß hat man, Herumgejuxe ist dagegen ein Verhalten. Das sind nicht Synonyme nur mit unterschiedlicher Bewertung. B) Gespräch und Gerede auch nicht. Ein Gerede kann man alleine ausführen. Dass es meist abwertend benutzt wird macht nicht jedes Herumgerede abwertend. Zwei Marketingleute etwa können sich über erfolgversprechende Kundeninteraktion unterhalten. "Dem Kunden schmeicheln, Ersparnis herausstellen, etwas Herumgerede - schon hatte ich den Vertrag in der Tasche".

Answer (score 16):

In addition to David Vogt's answer: Some of the verb + *Ge* constructs in popular speech combine with *Rum*, some not:

Verb + *Ge* + *Rum*

- Rumgelaber
- Rumgejuxe (obviously)
- Rumgeschreie (*Hört endlich mit dem Rumgeschreie auf!*)
- Rumgesumme
- Rumgebrumme
- Rumgezanke
- Rumgelache
- Rumgehüpfe
- Rumgehopse
- Rumgetolle
- Rumgerenne
- Rumgedudel (typically with a musical instrument, or a radio)
- Rumgeklimper (on a piano)
- Rumgefuhrwerke (rare, rather: *das Rumfuhrwerken*)
- Rumgeklopfe (here start craft trades or home improvement activities)
- Rumgehämmere
- Rumgesäge
- Rumgeschleife
- Rumgefeile
- Rumgeschnipple (with scissors, also: *Rumgeschnippel*)
- Rumgesauge (with a vacuum cleaner; could also refer to a suckling)
- Rumgetue
- Rumgekaspere (difficulties to find the correct spelling show us that all these words are never used in writing)
- Rumgeknutsche
- Rumgehure
- Rumgebumse

Contrary to that I am not aware of a popular *Rum* prefix for

- Gehabe

If one searches for reasons of semantical logic, I would suggest: all the *Rumge-* words refer to activities of a person that create noise or motion suitable to annoy others. *Gehabe*, in contrast, refers rather to a posture or attitude not actually emitting noise or motion.

The *Rumge-* double prefix is very productive. You can use it on any verb fitting the above description. So, you could try to use

- Rumgeföhne

if your girlfriend does not stop blow-drying her hair for hours. But I have never met that word in actual use.

Note that all these words are pretty much restricted to oral, casual communication. You would not find them in written communication (unless of course in literature depicting oral speech as in drama). Using them correctly in oral communication, however, would be an indicator of a high level of command of German. (Not least because they would be hard to find in a dictionary.)

Comment: Do these words all have the same gender? If so, what is it. Plus can they ever be plural?

Comment: @Wilson: Yes, all substantives are neuter. None of these has a valid plural since it is an abstract process description (as *das Hören*), the official term is [Singularetantum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularetantum).

Comment: "Rum-" stands for "herum-", which can be translated as "around, about", I think. dict.cc has an example here: https://www.dict.cc/german-english/ich+kaspere+herum.html  (herumkaspern = rumkaspern = to clown about)

Comment: Rumgehabe obviously refers to a person who owns ridiculous amounts of rum. "Sein Rumgehabe ist nicht mehr erträglich, er sollte lieber Whiskey kaufen."

Comment: @infinitezero: no, it never comes from a noun (Rum) - "Rumgehabe" is a coincidence purely because of its (almost illegal) shortcut - remember that "Herumgehabe" is the full version. This meaning of "Rumgehabe" practically only appears in (word) jokes. One would rather say "sein Gehabe über Rum" or "Rum-Gehabe".

Comment: I should have mentioned the pun was intended.

Comment: @infinitezero  In my understanding ***Rumgehabe*** is rather a word for the behaviour of a person who has been having too much rum, as *Gehabe* is posture or attitude. (Compare to ***Bierlaune***, the joyful mood of a person who has had a certain amount of beer.) The circumstance of owning a lot of rum (and being bold about it) would rather be ***Rumhaberei***.

Comment: @infinitezero  Continuing this line of thought, ***Rumgejuxe*** can of course also be understood as a joking attitude under influence of rum, as ***Schnapslaune*** refers to people being loud and either funny or agressive after consumption of brandy.

Comment: @AmigoJack : He was probably just rumgejuxing.

Answer (score 9):

A "Jux" is a joke or a prank. "Rumgejuxe" is the act of joking around, not necessarily in a nice way. If some people want to work seriously and others just fool around, the serious guys might say: stop that "Rumgejuxe". "Rumgejuxe" is rather colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

**The closer your word is to the proper, correct, precise, formal word for the action, the more respect you have for the way it's being done.**
If the word you use is close to, but not exactly "correct", you're just being casual (and as somebody pointed out, you're probably speaking, not writing).  If you get further away, you're being disrespectful or downright insulting.

Example: your *Rumgejuxe*.  *Juxen* is a correct, formal word for *joking*, and *rum* is short for *herum* (around), so *juxen* means you're joking around, casually, like with your buddies.  *Juxerei* is another version.  These are not insulting, merely casual.

Now, if you use a word that could be applicable, is more generic and further from the proper word, e.g., *getue* or *rumgetue* (doing around), it starts to get into the realm of serious disrespect. You're saying what's being done might not even be  recognizable as joking, it's so bad.  If you were to use *geschrei* (screaming), this is a flatly incorrect description of the action, and thus very far from correct, and definitely insulting.

In English this is sort of like saying you saw someone's trumpet *performance* vs *show* vs *messing around* vs *screeching*.

Comment: I would inject that this differs from region to region. While getting away from the proper formal form of a word has a meaning, this is not always disrespectful or insulting. In Vienna, for example, using dialect forms of a term often denotes that it's meant less serious and also less insulting. So for example calling someone an "Idiot" is really insulting, since it is High German and thus meant seriously. Calling someone a "Wappler" for example, which is a Viennese word with a similar meaning, is often meant more jokingly. You would use that when messing around, for example.

Comment: So in one region Rumgejuxe might be used by someone who can't stand the noise and bother that someone creates. In Vienna you wouldn't use the word "Jux", but Rumgekaspern would mean something very similar. But because it uses multiple casual markers it would be something a parent might use towards their child, that they love, when it's joking around.